# About android market to upload an application

Tags: android, localization, google-play

When my app upload to `android` market,Upload assets have a warnig message about this:

> This apk requests 1 permissions that users will be warned about
>   android.permission.INTERNET

I check the app of `manifest.xml`,I'm sure there are `manifest.xml` to join the line

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET
```

so...Why are there warning message about `android.permission.INTERNET`?

And another question,the Upload assets of  `"Localized to"`  appear unknown,
how to set this field about `"Localized to"`?

thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application end users will be notified before installation the application have full access to Internet, something like this (there are 3 permissions, in your case only "Network communication" will appear):

[image: Device screen shot]

Answer (score -1):

you need to add localized strings first and market will automatically recognizes them.
see [developer.android.com reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#creating-alternates)